# How to reset field if I click a button?

Tags: javascript

I have 3 radio button; APPROVE, REJECT and INTERVIEW

If i click REJECT, it is mandatory to choose from a dropdown menu why it is rejected. By default, the dropdown menu will appear 'Please select' on the field

If i click APPROVE or INTERVIEW, the dropdown menu will be disable

Now it is working fine

However, the problem is if i click REJECT then i choose one of the item in the dropdown menu, let say 'Documents Not Completed', after that if i click APPROVE or INTERVIEW, the field still show 'Documents Not Completed'

What i want to do is if i choose REJECT, then i choose the reason from the dropdown menu, then i want to change to APPROVE or INTERVIEW, i want the dropdown menu field automatically reset and back to 'Please Selec'.

Can you guys help me?

Comment: please add some code

Comment: what is your old working code, we can help making edits in that previous code..

Answer (score 0):

**HTML using inline JS:**

```
<select id="reason">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">Doc Not Complete</option>
  <option value="2">Date is not prefered</option>
  <option value="3">Location issue</option>
</select>

<input onclick="document.getElementById('reason').value = '';" type="radio" name="approve" value="approve">
```

**Using Jquery and HTML :**

This should reset your dropdown to the first option. Here's the markup

```
<select id="reason">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">Doc Not Complete</option>
  <option value="2">Date is not prefered</option>
  <option value="3">Location issue</option>
</select>

<input onclick="resetOptions();" type="radio" name="appove" value="appove">
```

Jquery function

```
function resetOptions() {
    $("#reason option:first").attr("selected", true);
}
```